# Hide load more btn when all objects are displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a struggle here. 
I'm using jquery to load more content, and want to check if all divs with the class .employee are displayed, and if they are, hide the load more button. I will never know how many objects there are. So my html looks like this. (repeating once for every employee).

```
<div class="employee">
<p> </p>
</div>
```

And my javascript

```
$(function () {
  $(".employee").slice(0, 4).show();
  $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".employee:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
      if ($(".employee:hidden").length == 0) {
          $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
      }
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      }, 1500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the button when there are no more hidden `.employee` objects as follows:

```
  ...
  if ($(".employee:hidden").length == 0) {
    $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#loadMore").hide();  //ADD THIS
  }
  ...
```